# MPDF NO ME INSERTA LOS ESTILOS

Tags: php, mpdf

Cordial Saludo,

Estoy tratando de generar un pdf con MPDF, pero no me inserta estilos al documento, este es el codigo

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//VENDOR PARA MPDF
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

//CUERPO PARA EL PDF
require_once __DIR__ . '/Plantilla_PDF/Plantilla.php';

//CSS PARA EL CUERPO DEL PDF
$css = file_get_contents('Plantilla_PDF/style.css');

use mPDF;

$mpdf = new \mPDF('c','A4');

$plantilla = getPlantilla();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($css, 2);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($plantilla);


$mpdf->Output();
exit;

?>
```

Y Asi se ve en la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso la ultima version de MPDF y PHP 7.2.8

Quedo atento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$css = file_get_contents('style.css'); // css
$pdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
```

Cree la variable `$css` y luego uso la funcion `file_get_contents('')` donde colocas la ruta de tu archivo CSS. Luego colocas la variable $css dentro del WriteHTML.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias amigo, en su tiempo lo solucione de la misma forma que dices, gracias por el aporte para otra gente